# JavaFX Calculator Application Set On Action Events

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to create a JavaFX program that takes the first number and the second number from the user and adds, multiply, subtracts, or divides based on which button the user selects and displays the result in the text field. I've created the methods and have my classes set up correctly, but I'm not sure why my events are not working when I click a button. Any type of direction would be appreciated. I'm using Eclipse also. Thanks

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
           BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Calculator.fxml"));
           Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
           scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.show();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Application.launch(args);
   }
}
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class CalculatorController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField tf3;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf2;
    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd;
    @FXML
    private Button btnDivide;
    @FXML
    private Button btnSubtract;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf1;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMultiply;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btnAdd.setOnAction(e -> Add());
        btnSubtract.setOnAction(e -> Subtract());
        btnMultiply.setOnAction(e -> Multiply());
        btnDivide.setOnAction(e -> Divide());
    }

    private void Add() {

        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        int result = n1 + n2;

        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    private void Subtract() {

        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        int result = n1 - n2;

        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    private void Multiply() {

        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        int result = n1 * n2;

        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    }

    private void Divide() {

        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        int result = n1 / n2;

        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    }
}
```

fxml.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <items>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="151.0" layoutY="54.0" text="Number 1:" />
            <Label layoutX="151.0" layoutY="98.0" text="Number 2:" />
            <Label layoutX="151.0" layoutY="140.0" text="Number 3:" />
            <TextField fx:id="tf1" layoutX="284.0" layoutY="49.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="tf2" layoutX="284.0" layoutY="93.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="tf3" layoutX="284.0" layoutY="135.0" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnAdd" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add" />
            <Button fx:id="btnSubtract" layoutX="234.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Subtract" />
            <Button fx:id="btnMultiply" layoutX="362.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Multiply" />
            <Button fx:id="btnDivide" layoutX="479.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Divide" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </items>
</SplitPane>
```

Comment: **Unrelated:** Please make sure you format your code with proper indents and such before posting here so it's easier to read (I did go ahead and update the format for you this time). Also, Java naming conventions state that method names should be camel-cased, not capitalized (as in `Add()`, Subtract()`, etc)

Comment: Now, when you say your buttons are "not working," what exactly do you mean? Nothing happens or you get incorrect results?

Comment: Also, the code you posted does not compile. In `Main`, you declare the root element as a `BorderPane` but the `FXML` defines a `SplitPane`.

Answer (score 1):

You never defined a controller class for the FXML layout.

This can be done in one of two ways:

**1) Within the FXML file itself:**

In the root element of your FXML file, you need to specify a `fx:controller` attribute:

```
fx:controller="CalculatorController"
```

So, your root `SplitPane` element would look like this:

```
<SplitPane fx:controller="calculatorSample.CalculatorController" dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
           orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

If you're using SceneBuilder to build your layout, you can set the controller in the "Controller" section on the left:

[image: screenshot]

---

**2) Within your `Main` class:**

Especially useful if you need to configure the controller before loading the layout, you can specify the controller with the `FXMLLoader`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Calculator.fxml");
loader.setController(new CalculatorController());
Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
```